FileSytemWatcher error event to Observable
The "Creating Observable Sequences" section of the e-book INTRODUCTION TO RX.NET (by Ian Griffiths and Lee Campbell) describes how to transform file system events generated by FileSystemWatcher, in IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs>. In this case, the “Error” event
generated by FileSystemWatcher is not processed in any way:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> ObserveFileSystem(string folder)
{
    return 
        // Observable.Defer enables us to avoid doing any work
        // until we have a subscriber.
        Observable.Defer(() =>
            {
                FileSystemWatcher fsw = new(folder);
                fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                return Observable.Return(fsw);
            })
        // Once the preceding part emits the FileSystemWatcher
        // (which will happen when someone first subscribes), we
        // want to wrap all the events as IObservable<T>s, for which
        // we'll use a projection. To avoid ending up with an
        // IObservable<IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs>>, we use
        // SelectMany, which effectively flattens it by one level.
        .SelectMany(fsw =>
            Observable.Merge(new[]
                {
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Created += h, h => fsw.Created -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Changed += h, h => fsw.Changed -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Renamed += h, h => fsw.Renamed -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Deleted += h, h => fsw.Deleted -= h)
                })
            // FromEventPattern supplies both the sender and the event
            // args. Extract just the latter.
            .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
            // The Finally here ensures the watcher gets shut down once
            // we have no subscribers.
            .Finally(() => fsw.Dispose()))
        // This combination of Publish and RefCount means that multiple
        // subscribers will get to share a single FileSystemWatcher,
        // but that it gets shut down if all subscribers unsubscribe.
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
}

I adapted the code for my purposes and taught it to catch errors. After receiving an Error event from FileSystemWatcher, the Observable will exit, notifying it via the onError handler.
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static class FileSystemWatcherExtension {
    public static IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> ToObservable(this IFileSystemWatcherWrapper @this) {
        var fswObservableWrapper = Observable.Defer(() => {
                @this.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                return Observable.Return(@this);
            })
            // Directory does not exist
            .Catch((ArgumentException exc) => Observable.Throw<IFileSystemWatcherWrapper>(exc))
            // Unknown exception
            .Catch((Exception exc) => Observable.Throw<IFileSystemWatcherWrapper>(exc))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount(2);

        var eventsFS = fswObservableWrapper
            .SelectMany(fsw =>
                Observable.Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Created += h, h => fsw.Created -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Changed += h, h => fsw.Changed -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Deleted += h, h => fsw.Deleted -= h),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Renamed += h, h => fsw.Renamed -= h))
            )
            .Select(evt => evt.EventArgs);

        var errorsObservation = fswObservableWrapper
            .SelectMany(fsw =>
                Observable.FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs>(
                    h => fsw.Error += h, h => fsw.Error -= h))
            .SelectMany(evt =>
                evt.EventArgs.GetException() switch {
                    // Too many file events have occurred for FileSystemWatcher's internal buffer to handle them.
                    InternalBufferOverflowException ovf => Observable.Throw<FileSystemEventArgs>(ovf),
                    //  Access to the directory is denied, it may have been deleted
                    Win32Exception fnfWin => Observable.Throw<FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist", @this.Path, fnfWin)),
                    var exc => Observable.Throw<FileSystemEventArgs>(exc)
                }
            );

        return eventsFS
            .Merge(errorsObservation)
            .Finally(() => {
                @this.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                @this.Dispose();
            })
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The auxiliary interface provides the ability to test components associated with <see cref="FileSystemWatcher"/>
/// </summary>
public interface IFileSystemWatcherWrapper : IDisposable {
    NotifyFilters NotifyFilter { get; set; }
    bool EnableRaisingEvents { get; set; }
    string Filter { get; set; }
    bool IncludeSubdirectories { get; set; }
    int InternalBufferSize { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }

    event FileSystemEventHandler? Changed;
    event FileSystemEventHandler? Created;
    event FileSystemEventHandler? Deleted;
    event ErrorEventHandler? Error;
    event RenamedEventHandler? Renamed;
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementing <see cref="IFileSystemWatcherWrapper"/> with <see cref="FileSystemWatcher"/>
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The class that consumes file system events will store a reference like
/// <see cref="IFileSystemWatcherWrapper"/>, and you can pass this implementation to the constructor,
/// and when testing a stub
/// </remarks>
public class FileSystemWatcherWrapper : FileSystemWatcher, IFileSystemWatcherWrapper { }

It seems to me that there is a problem with the current implementation: there is no guarantee that all normal filesystem events will arrive at the Observable before the error event is caught. That is, if there is an error, it is likely that some normal event will be lost.
Of course, you can try adding a Delay() before sending the error, but this will only reduce the likelihood of a problem occurring, but it will unreasonably slow down the system, including during testing.
Wrapping the error in Exceptional will be incorrect, because the developers did not give us any guarantees that after an error it is possible to restore the normal functionality of the FileSystemWatcher class. Therefore, an error must always terminate the observed sequence.
Final question: How to ensure that all normal events are received before an Observable terminates with an error?

Your translated Russian is better than most people's English.

"How to ensure that all normal events are received before an Observable terminates with an error?" - That's simply not possible: a FileSystemWatcher can (hypothetically) continue to raise events indefinitely into the future regardless of how and when FS-events and error-events are raised in relation to each other.

@Dai, Thanks, I suspected something similar. And if you narrow the question a little:
How can I be sure to get all the normal events that occurred before the error message before the Observable terminates with an error?
Now it begins to seem to me that this is also impossible.

I did some research and (at least in .NET Framework 4.8) the FileSystemWatcher has at most a single Win32 Overlapped IO event in-flight, though each means that all events (including .Error unless it's the InternalBufferOverflowEvent-error specifcally - or if the Win32 ReadDirectoryChangesW call failed) are serialized - which means: so-long as the thread that entered CompletionStatusChanged has not yet cycled back to Monitor to start the next ReadDirectoryChangesW then (for example, beacuse the same thread is running your observers) then you're safe... if you squint...

I say "if you squint" because the SynchronizatingObject property basically ruins everything because it can cause event-handlers to run according to some other scheduler - fortunately it looks like it's easy to prevent that happening by ensuring that no other code can see, touch, smell or adulterate your FileSystemWatcher object. So good luck.

@Dai, thanks for the clarification

After everything I've said so far - I've changed my opinion: I think you should ditch FileSystemWatcher entirely and instead set-up your own thread-pool and manage the LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE objects (used with ReadDirectoryChangesW) yourself so you have full control over what happens between Win32's overlapped IO completions and your Observable.

@Dai, The complexity of implementing the second solution outweighs any potential benefit for me. But for some it may really become necessary.
